# Is it possible to selft mute a member with discord.js?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js, mute

Recently with coronavirus, school is cancelled so I made a discord server for my class. People are not very familiar with Discord so I want a command that can selfmute people so that the course can start. I want everyone to be able to unmute if they want to ask a question to the teacher, hence the self-mute and not the server-mute.
I have tried this code but it's not working because the *.selfmute(true)* is made for the bot.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require("./config.json");

const prefix = "!";
client.on("message", (message) => {
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "mute")) {
    let channel = message.member.voice.channel;
    for (let member of channel.members) {
        member[1].voice.setSelfMute(true);
    }
}
});

client.login(config.token);
```

Does anyone know how to do this ? Thanks for the help.

PS: sorry for my english, it's not my native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot self-mute or self-deafen a user other than the client's user.

The [documentation for `setSelfMute`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=setSelfMute) says:

> Self-mutes/unmutes the bot for this voice state.

Also, if you attempt to self-mute a user that will isn't the client user you will get this error:

```
Error [VOICE_STATE_NOT_OWN]: You cannot self-deafen/mute on VoiceStates that do not belong to the ClientUser.
```

---

Alternatively, you could mute them normally and then have a command to unmute them.

Comment: As I want them to be able to unmute themselves whenever they want, I'll give up on this idea. Thanks for your reply !

Comment: How can i use them?? i did `message.member.setSelfMute(true)` not working

Comment: @BrokenSoul [`setSelfMute`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=setSelfMute) is a method on `VoiceState`, so use `message.member`[`.voice`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=voice)`.setSelfMute(true)`. Note that this will only work for the bot user, so doing this is probably pointless. If you want to self-mute the bot, just do `message.guild.me.voice.setSelfMute(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

So the method `setSelfMute` is only for the bot, documentation can be found [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=setSelfMute)!
To make this happen to a user, there is also a documentation about that [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=setMute)! I will edit the message with the code as soonest as possible. It will include 2 ways: 1. Regular Command with prefix, 2. Slash Command (Will come later... - Documentation [here](https://discord.dev/interactions/slash-commands/))