# How do I make a discord bot that soft mutes(not server mute) everyone in the voice channel so that they can umute themselves when they want?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I made a discord bot to mute everyone in the voice channel but it server mutes them.
I want the bot to soft mute them so that they can unmute themselves when they want.
How do I do that? I used the following code-

```
if(command === 'me'){
if (message.member.voice.channel)
{ 
message.channel.send('everyone shushed');
            
let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(message.member.voice.channel.id);
           
 for (const [memberID, member] of channel.members) 
{             
member.voice.setMute(true);         
 }
}}
```

Comment: Replace `const [memberID, member]` with just `const member`. If you need the ID you can use `member.id`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60689223/12514997

Comment: This is certainly helpful, thanks. Just need to find other method to self-mute people.